# Keep getting permissions error gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, circleci-2.0

I am trying to integrate CircleCi with gcloud Kubernetes engine.

1. I created a service account with Kubernetes Engine Developer and Storage Admin roles.
2. Created CircleCi yaml file and configured CI.

Part of my yaml file includes:

```
docker:
            - image: google/cloud-sdk
        environment:
            - PROJECT_NAME: 'my-project'
            - GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID: 'my-project-112233'
            - GOOGLE_COMPUTE_ZONE: 'us-central1-a'
            - GOOGLE_CLUSTER_NAME: 'my-project-bed'
        steps:
            - checkout
            - run:
                  name: Setup Google Cloud SDK
                  command: |
                      apt-get install -qq -y gettext
                      echo $GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY > ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
                      gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
                      gcloud --quiet config set project ${GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID}
                      gcloud --quiet config set compute/zone ${GOOGLE_COMPUTE_ZONE}
                      gcloud --quiet container clusters get-credentials ${GOOGLE_CLUSTER_NAME}
```

Everything runs perfectly except that the last command:

```
gcloud --quiet container clusters get-credentials ${GOOGLE_CLUSTER_NAME}
```

It keeps failing with the error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission(s) for "projects/my-project-112233/zones/us-central1-a/clusters/my-project-bed". See https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#gke_service_account_deleted for more info.
```

I tried to give the ci account the role of project owner but I still got that error.

I tried to disable and re-enable the Kubernetes Service but it didn't help.

Any idea how to solve this? I am trying to solve it for 4 days...

Answer (score 1):

I removed the service account and recreated it (with same name and roles). Generated a new key and updated the CI and suddenly it worked. gcloud glitch.